# Inject a library in angular ui-router on state resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm wondering if there is a way to resolve a library dependency on the resolve function of UI-router.

Something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.cart', {
                title    : "CART.TITLE",
                url      : '/cart',
                views    : {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/cart/cart.html',
                        controller : 'CartController as vm'
                    },
                },
                bodyClass: 'cart',
                resolve: { 
                    //fetch a library, ex. moment js
                    var moment = $http.get('moment.js');
                    body.append(moment);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You could try looking at the $q service which you could use to return a promise result after the library has loaded

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just trying to see if it possible to fetch a library only when user enters certain states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would do that but you can easily fetch a JS file within `resolve`. [Demo](http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/XdBzgM)

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('state1', {
    url: 'state1',
    templateUrl: 'state1.tpl.html'
  })
  .state('state2', {
    url: 'state2',
    templateUrl: 'state2.tpl.html',
    resolve: {
      external: ['$http', function($http) {
        var someJs = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jonaszuberbuehler/952c2f9a0c9e28557ed89c1e4d6fe8b7/raw/e6664811e1b34d9761500f4c46bfd2e1e2439d23/gistfile1.txt';
        return $http.get(someJs).then(function(result) {
          alert(result.data);
        });
      }]
    }
  });
```

Adding it to the DOM is another question.

Comment: Yes, the source is there, what you do with it is your choice (adding it to the DOM for example, or using evil `eval()`).

Comment: I updated the demo to add a new script tag containing the fetched source. But I'm not saying you should do that...